# Expand Synology SHR volume with varying disk sizes

Tags: raid, array, expansion

I'm looking for a clarification on SHR and how it handles expanding a volume when the volume contains varying disk sizes.

I've read the [Synology Documentation](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_Synology_Hybrid_RAID?) and it still isn't clear, because their use-case assumes that the original volume was created with equal disk sizes.

My current volume setup on a DS411 is:

1. 1TB
2. 2TB
3. 2TB
4. Empty

I'm looking to add a 1TB disk to slot 4. Is this possible? I keep reading that the disk that is added needs to be "equal or larger than" the existing disks, but in my case, is that => the *smallest* disk in the current volume, or => than the *largest* disk in the current volume.

Would I be able to add a 1TB disk to my volume? Or would I need to add a 2TB or greater disk?

Answer (score 2):

related to SHR:
yes, you can add so small HDD as is smallest in array = in your case 1 TB.

If I understand when you add to slot 4 next 1 TB HDD (expand SHR volume) you will have:
4x1TB in something like RAID 5 (that means 3 TB usable space)
and thank to SHR
also 2x1TB in something like mirror (means 1 TB usable space).
By my mind final usable space will be 4 TB (or more precisely something above 3 "real computer TB" (correctly TiB) ).

Answer (score 0):

You may add any disk brand / and technology as long as it is SATA in your case for your drive model and that is it the smallest of your array size's similair disk. I would like to politely correct the above poster that, you may for example insert even a 250GB disk in slot #4. What you may not do, is you may not downgrade to a smaller capacity that is already in that slot.

So for example, in your case when you put in the 1TB drive, you may not put in a 500GB drive there next month.

Enjoy your NAS!